# Do robots refer to User Agent in robots.txt using OR or AND manner

Tags: robots.txt

Let's say I have list of user agents in my robots.txt like

```
User-agent: Applebot
Disallow: something

User-agent: baiduspider
Disallow: something

User-agent: Bingbot
Disallow: something

User-agent: *
Disallow: something
```

Would bots reference User Agents in OR manner or AND manner? If Bingbot crawls this site, do Bingbot rules and * rules apply together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Google](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt#grouping-of-records), each `User-agent` line starts a new group of records and only one group of group-member records is valid for a particular crawler. The correct group is the one with the most specific user-agent.

So, Bingbot should only read the rules after `User-agent: Bingbot`, and not the rules after `User-agent: *`.

Comment: Thanks, you are right! Tested this on Webmasters tool